# How to get or set a character at specified index in fortran string?

Tags: string, indexing, fortran, fortran95

```
program polynomialCalc
  character(Len=100):: polynomialString="fds"

  Do i=1, Len(Trim(polynomialString))    
    Print*, i, polynomialString(i:1)
  END Do
END program polynomialCalc
```

I have no idea why code showed above returns only first character "f". I would be appreciate for explanation and good solution, how to handle this.

The other question is how can I set a character at specified index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a specific character, use the same index for the start and end of your substring range.  For example:

```
polynomialString(i:i)
```

Will be the single character at position `i`.

Comment: ...
I expected that it works in that way: polynomialString(index: length). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

To set a character at a specific location you can do

```
polynomialString(pos:pos) = 'c'
```

To set characters from a position to a position, you can do

```
polynomialString(posFrom:posTo) = "12"
```

You can play around with them and see how they work.